# Angular: changes in router outlet is hiding the following element

Tags: angular, safari

```
<div>
    <div style="position: sticky;position: -webkit-sticky;top: 0;background: white;z-index: 2;">
        <app-header></app-header>
        <app-env-selector></app-env-selector>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

With this code, all the components are loading in initial stage but when the content is modified in `<router-outlet>`, `<app-footer>` is getting disappeared. With resizing of screen I am able to see the footer again. This issue appears only in safari. I would be thankful if someone helps me fix this.

Comment: don't you think you should add more information or try to create a working prototype using stackblitz/ plunker. So others can understand your issue. As of now it's completely unclear.